# Ubuntu 14.04 VM resizing in VMWare fusion 7 whenever a terminal is opened?

Tags: ubuntu, osx, vmware

On a computer at work, we have a virtual machine running that resizes the whole VMWare window whenever you launch a new CLI terminal window within the VM. Any ideas how to fix it? It's quite annoying.

Also, if you do `sudo -s`, it does the same thing. Say I have VMWare maximized, when I open terminal, launch a new terminal window, or type `sudo -s` (and probably any other user change, though I haven't tested) the VM will get much smaller.

The host is a Mac Pro with Mountain Lion running VMWare Fusion Pro 7, and the guest is an Ubuntu 14.04 VM.